# Rufus rendered USB inoperable?

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, boot, bootable-media, rufus

I just used Rufus 3.13.1730(Portable) to make a Windows 10 bootable USB for my secondary machine.  I unfortunately didn't realize I had selected the wrong format (I think UEFI is the acronym?).  When I attempted to boot with it to install Windows 10 on that machine, the program gave me an error/warning that I needed to re-make the USB with the MBR/Bios format.

So I unplugged the USB stick as instructed on screen, and then restarted that machine.  Bringing the stick back to my main machine, it is now non-existant to anything that can recover the drive.  It's visible under Device Manager as "USB Mass Storage Device", and even Avast asks if I want to scan it for malware.  I can go to it by typing in "E:" in my file browser, but it is just completely blank with no files.

I cannot reformat it, as no actual program I've used detects its existence, and the USB stick is basically just...gone.  Even Rufus itself can no longer detect the USB stick, even with the "List USB Hard Drives" option.  And since there's no way to manually type in what drive to format in Rufus (or any other USB formatter that I've found), I am unsure of what to do.

Windows (my main machine runs 7) does not detect the stick through CMD's chkdsk, nor the file explorer, and if I force the system to recognize it by just going to "E:" manually (the drive disappears from the listings again when I click away from the drive), right clicking on the drive and selecting "Format" does nothing.  Windows doesn't even attempt it, the right click menu just closes.

I'm hoping Akeo sees this post, as I saw them answering other questions about their software.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, first of all, I hope that the steps you describe hardly point to Rufus having rendered your USB inoperable.

Up to the point where you replugged the drive back onto your original machine, there was nothing wrong with it, since it had been properly detected then, and, as you should be able to tell, there's simply no way Rufus could have "magically" rendered your drive inoperable between the time you unplugged the drive from the computer you planned to boot it on and plugged it back on the computer you created the drive with (The message you saw when you tried to boot the USB is a simple text output produced by invoking basic BIOS functions, and not some kind of fancy executable that's accessing the USB. As a matter of fact, the [code to display that message](https://github.com/pbatard/rufus/blob/master/res/mbr/msg.S) requires no knowledge of USB, and even if it was buggy and wrote garbage data all over the drive —not a small feat considering that the code is designed to simply invoke BIOS calls to **read** and display data— you would just end up with an unpartitioned drive that any application could repartition and reformat since this would not, in any way, make the drive undetectable).

So, by the looks of it, your flash drive simply **failed** when you plugged it back on that other computer, and [Rufus had nothing whatsoever to do with that](https://github.com/pbatard/rufus/wiki/FAQ#Help_Rufus_damaged_my_flash_drive).

Moreover, if it's not detected any longer on any of your computers, then there's nothing any software can do to salvage it. Your drive is dead and you will just have to replace it.

What I usually recommend, as a last resort, is to see if your drive is recognized at all on a non Windows machine (e.g. Linux). But considering that your drive can't be listed in Rufus any longer, it is most likely dead.

Comment: I apologize, I didn't mean to make it sound like Rufus itself was the cause of the ghost drive.  I was merely extremely confused at the situation, as I had never really experienced such a thing.  My computer was even recognizing the drive audibly, sensing I was plugging in a Plug-and-Play device.

Unfortunately, I do not have any other machines to test on, as they all run Windows here, so I will have to accept that, somehow, the USB failed.  It is a few years old, so I guess I shouldn't be surprised.  I was thinking that was the problem.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't already, try looking for the drive in Window's Disk Management. You can start it from Run (<kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>), with `diskmgmt.msc`. Find the Drive, and right click > "Delete Volume", on all partitions. Then you should be able to right click > "Format".

Answer (score 0):

[image]

```
CMD (as administrator)

DISKPART

LIST DISK (Find the USB disk number eg. disk 3)

SELECT DISK 3

CLEAN

EXIT
```

Then you can go into windows disk manager and it will be back to normal